# How do i correct the border not showing correctly in this card?

Tags: flutter, dart

So i have this card, and it has a border radius. however, as in the picture, the top half doesn't show the borders like the bottom half does. How do i make it so the top half also has the border radius showing up while maintaining the same layout?

This is the card code:

```
Card(
  elevation: 2,
  borderOnForeground: true,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(10)),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 20.w,
    height: 25.w,
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            'images/1_1.png',
            height: 20.w,
            width: 20.w,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                subcategorias[index],
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                maxLines: 2,
                overflow:
                    TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 7.sp),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

[card model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPqXU.png)

Supposedly, the "borderOnForeground: true" which already defaults to true should make it so the border renders above the content, but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` to your `Card`:

```
Card(
  elevation: 2,
  borderOnForeground: true,
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
)
```